# java.lang.VerifyError: com/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I'm getting weird crash when few of my customer are opening my app that is using Crashlytics:

**Android version: Android 4.4**

**Device: Xperia Z3v (D6708)**

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore$Builder.build(CrashlyticsCore.java:186)
    at com.my.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:74)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4464)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also happens on **Samsung Galaxy S4** and **Samsung Galaxy Note ||**

This is my code:

```
public class GlobeKeeperApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
            Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build(), new Crashlytics());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize Crashlytics.");
        }
    }
}
```

**After contacting Fabric support team, they told me to try and move the initialization to my Main Activity, so I also tried that without success..**

*Fabric team still didn't get back to me with a solution.*

Comment: Did you omit the actual error message, or does Crashlytics throws VerifyErrors?

Comment: This is all the info I see on the **Play Developer Console**

Comment: Try to get a more meaningful message because that one is useless for troubleshooting. Also, you may want to upgrade/downgrade Crashlytics or contact them

Comment: I got this error, and rebuild project. Then i saw Realm caused the error. Then i enabled Multidex and it is all solved